# How to send push notification to different package name apk from the single app on fire base console?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap

Is it possible to use the single google-service.json file in multiple APKs with different package name to send the push notification or is there any way to send the push notification to multiple APKs with different package name from the single app account on firebase console? 
In our system, we are creating apps using PhoneGap with Firebase Cloud Messaging Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your firebase project, settings and add new project, download json from different package name for different apk. To send notification to selected apk, select that apk whene you want to send notification to that app.

Comment: But we need to use like single JSON file for different apk having the different package name because we have a system by which user can create multiple apps so we don't have a way to put json file manually while creating the apps.

Comment: @Dheeraj did you found any solution to this? Or is mandatory to send tokenId by tokenId instead of only 1 push to the specific's package name